# Bower + RequireJS multiple files

Tags: requirejs, bower

I have a bower package containing 2 requirejs modules -

```
- src
 - a.js <- this is the primary package/amd module which lists b.js as a module dependency
 - b.js
```

So we end up with something like this:

```
 // a.js
 define(['./b'], function(b){})
```

The problem is that when I add this package as a dependency of a separate project, that the require.js configuration will only successfully resolve the path for module a.

What is the best solution for maintaining an bower package consisting of multiple rjs modules, without manually configuring the rjs `packages` key in the parent project?

I would like to get to the point where I can successfully auto build my rjs configurations from the bower.json, as seen with grunt bower and other npm build modules.

Part of me feels that this is bowers responsibility, as there should be an option to define a package as multiple files.

I also suspect there may be a way to concatenate the modules into a single file, but am a little unsure of how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The solution involves concatenating the said files to make one bower package.

```
// This will build all 3 files into a single concatenated pkg
// 'efficient-frontier', 'everestjs', 'sem-campaign'
// nmp install -g rjs
// r.js -o require.build.js optimize=none
// Below is a file in my root named 'require.build.js'
({
    baseUrl: "",
    paths: {
      everestjs: './vendor/bower/everestjs/index',
      requirejs: './vendor/bower/requirejs/require',
      'jquery.cookie': './vendor/bower/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie',
      'sem-campaign': 'dist/shared/sem-campaign',
      'efficient-frontier': 'dist/shared/efficient-frontier',
      jquery: './vendor/bower/jquery/jquery'
    },
    // Exclude the packages you expect to be included in the parent project
    exclude: ['jquery','jquery.cookie'],
    name: "sem-campaign",
    out: "./dist/sem-campaign.js"
})
```

The final package bower is 3 concatenated rjs modules. The package in this example is sem-campaign.